# Customer Custom Attribute and Save Value when Save Customer

Tags: magento2.2, customer-attribute

I have to add custom Dropdown attribute to customer. Which have 3 options like Pending, Approved and Disapproved. So when we save customer i have to save this field value.

For this i have added field in the database table and created Dropdown in admin side form. but i am not understanding how to save this field data.

When status is changed also i have to send email. I am thinking to override Save controller of admin but not sure.

Please help me.

Comment: Please suggest me best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add attribute to the customer not Column to the Database.

Please refer to this article to add attribute to the customer in correct way,

https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-create-customer-custom-attribute-in-magento-2-0/

in this article they added text attribute, you need to add select type instead for your case

when you create the attribute in the correct way, you will find it in the admin customer page and will be saved automatically as any other value.

for sending email you need to use the events, there is event (customer_save_after)

You have to check the original value and the new value, if the values are not the same that mean you changed the value of this attribute, if the value is changed then you can send email to the customer

it should be like this

```
{
    $oCustomer = $observer->getCustomer();
    $origin_data = $oCustomer->getOrigData("{your_attribute}");
    $new_data = $oCustomer->getData("your_attribute");
    // send email here
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: It's giving error
Call to undefined method Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer::getOrigData()
Call to undefined method Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer::getData()